# Setting up Github Pages from a forked repo

Tags: github, github-pages

I've once setup a Github page from a repo I created. Process was go to settings > Github Pages > Source > Select "master branch" > Save

And thereafter it goes live. I've cloned a repo for html/css CV https://six-wars.github.io/html-resume-template/ (my clone https://github.com/Six-wars/html-resume-template). Following the same process I've tried checking to see if the github page works but it returns `Site not found`.

The repo has only one branch `master` and it also contains `index.html` so I'm a bit confused as to where the issue is.

Comment: Is this your first time using GitHub Pages? Now open your Page to see what it happens?

Comment: The first time an account start to use GitHub Pages will have wait for a period of time (approx. 10min) for GitHub to setup something [citation needed]. This will only occur for the first time, all modifications are instantly from then on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question, I guess https://six-wars.github.io/html-resume-template is the saying `Site not found` GitHub Page which is said "not working".

This seems the first time this account using GitHub Pages. As the [document of GitHub Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/) says, (after you make the first commit of your repository that triggers GitHub Pages)

> GitHub does all the work to direct visitors to `username.github.io` to view your new website. This can take up to 10 minutes.

And, now is 40 minutes passed from the question being asked, and [this website mentioned in the question](https://six-wars.github.io/html-resume-template) can be seen now.