# Blank page showing on angular cli project on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, angular-cli, github-pages

This is my first angular project using angular CLI 15 with a Firebase database.
I finally got my project to "upload" just for it to be a blank page.
Using the web inspector tools I found an issue "`loading resources`".

[image: errors]

I've seen some posts saying about changing the base `href` which I did and also about the `dist` folder.
I don't know what that is and I saw issues that `ng serve` doesn't create it anymore, so I'm even more lost at how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, GitHub pages want to access your resources right at the root folder of the (private it seems) repository.

As in this issue, add a . in your links/src: `"./path/to/aFile"`
And make sure the path refers to a file from the your repository, in the branch you have selected in your [GitHub page configuration source](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23058#discussioncomment-3238887).

---

If possible, try and use [`angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages`](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages) to publish your pages, possibly as a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/blob/64651e64c62839cb8f800ae2782292cccf12ca1c/docs/README_environment_github_actions.md).
It [latest release](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/releases) adds support for Angular v15.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was originally using what you suggested above and got this result. The I used your suggestion in adding the ./ and now it shows my readme when deployed. Would the fact that this repo is forked from my school's project repo affect this at all? It's private so I can't change the visibility of my forked repo.

Comment: @MasterYoshi97 A fork should not be an issue (as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51114264/6309)). Is showing your `README` the result you wanted? If not, did you set up the right [publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)?